# moving and renaming a folder in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, mv

I want to ask a question about moving and renaming folders in linux simultaneously.

Consider I am on my desktop and want to move a folder to another location.

`folder1` exists at `~/folder1`

If I want to move it to the desktop, I do the following command:

```
mv ~/folder1 ~/Desktop
```

However, if I want to move *and* rename the folder, for some reason this is the command:

```
mv ~/folder1 ~/Desktop/folder2
```

I'm confused here slightly.

If `folder2` does not exist, `folder1` is renamed as `folder2`, keeping all the contents.

However, if `folder2` does exist, it simply slots `folder1` into `folder2` i.e.

```
~/Desktop/folder2/folder1
```

I thought that if `folder2` does not exist, it simply creates `folder2` and inserts `folder1` into it as per the moving of a file with `mv`.

Why does the folder simply get renamed from `folder2` to `folder1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explained the mv workflow quite clearly here.

the command 'mv' first checks the destination and checks if it is available.
Destination if not available - This source file is moved and renames the file.
Destination if available and is a folder - This source file is moved into the destination folder
Destination if available and is a file - This source file is moved into the destination folder and gets overwritten

Ref:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv